# Parsing an array element and adding to hash

Tags: ruby

In Ruby,I've an array element, let's say

```
arr[1] = "key1=vale1|key2=value2|key3=value3".
```

Now I have another array which contains hstore data e.g

```
h_arr=[hkey1=>hvalue1, hkey2=>hvalue2]
```

How can I add `arr[1]` element to `h_arr` and be able to get the result something like this

```
h_arr=[hkey1=>hvalue1, hkey2=>hvalue2, key1=>value1, key2 => value2, key3 => value3]
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What is the relation between arr[1] and the result, particularly, what is the rule that converts vale1 to value1 but not value2 to valuue2 or value3 to valuue3?

Answer (score 3):

```ruby
h_arr.merge!(Hash[*arr[1].split(/[=|]/)])
```

Note that I am assuming that `h_arr` is actually defined as just a Hash like below (as opposed to your syntax which evaluates to an array of a single item of the given hash):

```ruby
h_arr = {hkey1=>hvalue1, hkey2=>hvalue2}
```

If your syntax was indeed correct then merge to `h_arr[0]` instead of `h_arr`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
str = "key1=vale1|key2=value2|key3=value3"
h_arr = {'hkey1'=>'hvalue1', 'hkey2'=>'hvalue2'}

h1 = str.split('|').inject({}) {|f,c| f.update Hash[*c.split('=')] }

final = h_arr.merge(h1)

p final

#=> {"hkey1"=>"hvalue1", "hkey2"=>"hvalue2", "key1"=>"vale1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3"}
```

Please note that this kind of structures are in fact Hashes, not Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `yaml` to serialize/deserialize your data. Try something like this:

```
require "yaml"

# starting hash
hash = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2", :key3 => "value3"}

# create serial from hash
serial = hash.to_yaml

# show serial
puts serial
#=> --- 
#=> :key3: value3
#=> :key1: value1
#=> :key2: value2

# load hash from serialized string
new_hash = YAML.load(serial)

# show new hash
puts new_hash.inspect
#=> {:key3=>"value3", :key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```

After you have regular hash objects in Ruby, it's easy to use `Hash#merge` on them to combine them.

```
# voilà
hash1.merge(hash2)
```